# My Magento site sends sales email to all gmail email but won't send any emails to site specific emails

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento site sends sales email to all gmail email but doesn't send any emails to site specific emails. **For example:** when an order is received, we get order emails to abc@gmail.com and pqr@gmail.com (which has been setup as cc to receive the emails), but the site specific emails (like: xyz@sitename.com) do not get any emails.

Any solutions?

Comment: Seems like issue is related to your SMTP settings.